# Як перекласти абревіатуру WAGs?

Tags: переклад, from-english, неологізми

**WAGs** (wives and girlfriends) - абревіатура, яка є скорочення словосполучення "дівчат та дружин відомих людей (а не лише спортсменів, як про це пише на [Вікіпедії](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAGs))". Жодний із відомих онлайн перекладачів не може дати адекватного перекладу цієї абревіатури.

Як же її краще перекласти? ДІД (дівчата і дружини) чи ДТД (дівчата та дружини)? Чи може цю абревіатуру взагалі неможливо перекласти і варто її просто пояснити?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ДІД або ДТД не буде зрозуміло тим, заради кого Ви робите переклад. Ці абревіатури не вживаються в українській мові, тому краще уникайте їх. Або будьте впевнені, що читачі (якщо це для тексту) знають, про що іде мова. Наприклад:

> Вважається, що вперше абревіатура **ДТД (дівчата та дружини)** була використана у 2002 році.

ДІД звучить досить комічно...

Проте необов'язково навіть викорістовувати абревіатури. Дивіться, що роблять в деяких інших мовах: [Spielerfrau](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spielerfrau) (німецька), [Maria-chuteira](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria-chuteira) (португальська).

Тож я вважаю, що краще значення просто пояснити. Так буде зрозуміліше.